# How to resolve Facebook Instant Games uploading.zip file error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-instant-games

I have uploaded my .zip file of my game to Facebook Instant Games when an error pop up. It says "Game must reference to one of our supported SDKs via CDN."

I already put the script tag in head and body

```
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.com/en_US/fbinstant.7.0.js"></script>
```

and my fbapp-config.json

{
"instant_games": {
"platform_version": "RICH_GAMEPLAY",
"orientation": "PORTRAIT",
"navigation_menu_version": "NAV_BAR"
}
}

I also tried the CLI method in uploading the .zip file, but also gets the same error saying I must refer to their SDK via CDN.

Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Where did you add the script - in an `index.html` on the root level?

Comment: yes, as well as the fpapp-config.json

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this script tag instead?

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.latest.js"></script>
```

This worked for me when I just tried uploading a .zip file now.

Comment: I still got the error ;<

Comment: Just want to confirm - did you copy/paste or manually type in the script tag I shared? There is a subtle difference between yours and mine: "facebook.com" (yours) vs. "facebook.net" (mine) that could be easy to miss without copy/pasting. If you did indeed catch that difference and still got the error when using the "facebook.net" tag, I'll keep digging around to see if I can find something else that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Oh thank you, but I already solved it. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Great! What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the SDK URL to the following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/assets.php/en_US/fbinstant.latest.js
```

This works for me.
I found it in a sample file, I have just downloaded from facebook.

I hope it helps!